# datatables Sum values of each row with paging

Tags: datatables

I have a big table (5 cols x 116k rows) containing population numbers.
I need to sum the column containing the population and that this sum changes with the filters applied.
e.g. I might type a postcode in the filter and I need the sum of the population for this particular postcode.
(I'm using the main filter + the multi filters per columns https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html )

I tried using the sum api : https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/sum()

It works, but it only gives the sum of the visible rows.
How can I get the sum of all the rows, except those filtered out when I type something in the search fields ?

I also tried the footer callback method https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html
It also works but same problem: only sum of visible rows, not other pages.

I would prefer using the second method (footer callback) if possible, it's all in one place, easier to maintain imo.

Thanks!

Comment: server-side or client-side datatables?

Comment: client-side, pure JavaScript, static website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it finally

You have to use `{'search': 'applied'}` in `.column()`

In https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html

replace

```
.column( 4, { page: 'current'} )
```

with

```
.column( 4, {'search': 'applied'} )
```

Like this:

```
// Total over the search
searchTotal = api
    .column( 4, {'search': 'applied'} )
    .data()
    .reduce( function (a, b) {
        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
    }, 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

To sum all values using a "datatables" table which is server-side paging, you must provide `view all` from the `view dropbox` and get that value when viewed all.

You can find the `view all` functionality implementation in [this link](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html).

**OR**

Provide another Ajax Service URL that returns the total sum because the main purpose of datatables is to represent data in a well-structured form, not to sum all of the values.

Comment: I can't use the view all functionality because too many rows. already tried to disable paging but that slows the page to the point where it's unusable.

Comment: So my other suggestion is to generate another service URL that sends back the total sum. You know, datatables is just to represent data in a well-structured form.